# `folderselect` doesn't appear to work on mobile with Dropbox Chooser

Tags: dropbox-api

How can a user choose a folder in the mobile client for the Chooser?

On Mobile:
[image]

On Desktop:
[image]

Comment: (Apologies for my original answer. I thought you meant the native mobile versions, not mobile web.) Thanks for the report! We'll look into it.

Comment: This should be working on mobile web now too.